# Ubuntu 14.04 package dependency issue

Tags: python, ubuntu

Host: Ubuntu 14.04

When I executed a script, I got the following issue:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
dh-python : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
lsb-release : Depends: python3 but it is not going to be installed

Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
ubuntu-minimal : Depends: python3 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: resolvconf

E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I have entered `apt-get -f install` and executed the script again. However, it did not make any change.

The python version on my system is:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13)
```

Comment: you need to use python3

Comment: try `python3 your_file.py`

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 comes with python3 also.

Comment: Does it mean I should switch the default python version to 3 instead of 2 ? If so, can you let me know how to change it. thanks

Comment: @Hackaholic I executed the shell script. There are some package dependencies in it I guess.

Comment: @user3815726 Isn't it a Python script?

Comment: @KevinGuan It isn't.

Comment: @user3815726 Ah, understand now. Did you install Python 3? Try `python3 --version`.

Comment: @KevinGuan I did. alias should work. would you post your reply in answer ?

Comment: Seems like Michael did that :)

Comment: @KevinGuan Thank you too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python 3 is the key here.  You are using Python 2.

So, I highly recommend using Anaconda for your purposes.  It will allow you to switch between Python2 and Python3

In your browser download the [Anaconda installer for Linux](http://continuum.io/downloads.html), then in your terminal window type the following, replacing the file path and name with the path and name of your downloaded install file. (There is also a gui installer that sets up a PATH entry)

Follow the prompts on the installer screens, and if unsure about any setting, simply accept the defaults, as they can all be changed later:

```
bash ~/Downloads/Anaconda-2.3.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

Now add `conda` to your path

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/anaconda/bin
```

*replace the path with the correct path to `anaconda/bin` wherever it lives on your machine

Now create an environment that uses python3

```
conda create --name test python=3
```

Activate your environment

```
source activate test
```

You will see an environment `(test)` in front of your command prompt.  Test can be renamed to suit your needs.

Verify:

```
python --version
```